# Regular expression matching X session identifiers?

Tags: x11, xorg, regular-expression

I'm trying to create a utility for extracting the first display that a user is physically at using `grep` and `awk`:

```
$ w | grep -P '^naftuli' | awk '{print $3;}'
:0
reprisal
tmux(2464).%0
tmux(2464).%1
tmux(2464).%2
```

I have seen variant X session identifiers, is there a standard format that I could implement a regular expression for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a modern Unix system, there are two types of X displays: local or (TCP) remote. A local display name is `:` followed by a number, and optionally but rarely followed by `.` and a screen number. A remote display is a host name or IP address followed by a local display name. Thus, in ERE syntax:

```
/([-.0-9A-Za-z]+|\[[0-9A-Fa-f:]\]):[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/
```

In practice, “it's X if and only if there's a `:`” should work.

Comment: Thank you, as always Gilles, just got back to this today for [this](https://github.com/naftulikay/autopulse/issues/1).